# SOQL for All Activities Under a Role

Tags: soql, activities, role-hierarchy

I have a report that pulls back all activities under a role but it can only pull back a years worth of activities since Salesforce archives them. So I am wondering if I can take the filters on my report and turn it into a SOQL query so I can get more than a year of activities. I have it figured out expect for the all activities under role filter.

[image: Report Filter]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the SOQL Query builder in workbench? 
https://workbench.developerforce.com/query.php